# Could travertine buildup seal up cracks in limestone?

Tags: geology, mineralogy, limestone, cavern

So after a recent freeze in Texas the following overhang collapsed. Presumably water in existent cracks froze and made the cracks even bigger as the water expanded. Combined that with an increase in the weight of the overhang and it fell off.

My question is...  let's say this freeze hadn't happened in Texas and that Texas wouldn't see any freezes for the next three years. As the springs behind the falls continues to produce water could travertine build up in the existent cracks form an adhesive, effectively "healing" the overhang from past freeze induced damage?

[image]